# Powershell, sum totals from text files

Tags: powershell, text, sum

I have a script that creates a monthly total of daily use listed in text files.
Each daily stats file is in this format:

```
location,Feeder,total,endpoints
Oaklake,1,11153,310
oaklake,2,26214,291
oaklake,3,4593,147
oaklake,4,5279,145
```

Here is the relevant portion of the script I'm having trouble with:

```
#create list of last month's days
if ((get-date).day -eq 2) {
    $fullmonth = "location,Feeder,Usage,endpoints`n"
    $year = (get-date).addmonths(-1).year
    $month = (get-date).addmonths(-1).month
    $days = 1..[datetime]::daysinmonth($year,$month) |
        %{(get-date -day $_ -month $month -year $year).toshortdatestring()}

#select the file for each particular day and add it's content to $fullmonth
foreach ($day in $days) {
    $dayfile = ls "c:\powershell\locationUse\summaries" |
        ?{$_.creationtime -gt $day -and $_.creationtime -lt $(get-date $day).adddays(1).toshortdatestring()} |
        sort creationtime | select -last 1 | gc | select -skip 1
    $fullmonth += $($dayfile | out-string)
}
$fullmonth | export-csv ./fullmonthtest.csv -notypeinformation
```

My problem is the final output of fullmonthtest.csv is a repetition of the last day of summary
files, like so:

```
location,Feeder,total,endpoints
Oaklake,1,11153,310
oaklake,2,26214,291
oaklake,3,4593,147
oaklake,4,5279,145
Oaklake,1,11153,310
oaklake,2,26214,291
oaklake,3,4593,147
oaklake,4,5279,145
Oaklake,1,11153,310
oaklake,2,26214,291
oaklake,3,4593,147
oaklake,4,5279,145
Oaklake,1,11153,310
oaklake,2,26214,291
oaklake,3,4593,147
oaklake,4,5279,145
```

Am I using the "+=" method incorrectly or something?  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I tried that just now, and still same incorrect results.  It doesn't seem to matter whether the .creationtime is compared against a .toshortdatestring() or just a date-time object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I discovered the content of the month's worth of files was identical in each one.  My script was working correctly, I just didn't verify the sources of my data.  That's what I get for working with data created from and old version of my current script.  Oops!  Thanks for the response though Mathias.